# Django many-to-many без айдишников

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть модель со списком телефонов

```
class Users(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="ФИО")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="Номер телефона", help_text=' в формате +79123456789')
```

Есть модель с входящими звонками

```
class Calls(models.Model):
    authdate = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Время")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="Номер телефона")
```

Как соединить их, чтоб в админке получить связанный список?

Comment: Почему без id-шников?

Comment: По моему, тут больше подходит один-ко-многим. У одного юзера много звонков. То есть, если это телефонная книга, например, то у любого контакта будет от 0 до бесконечности входящих. Но у любого входящего - только один контакт

Comment: Поле не уникально в обоих таблицах, точнее почти уникально, но делать его уникальным не получится. Ещё момент в том что если сделать foreign key то если ключ в списке отсутствует, то изчезает из поиска по такая запись.

Comment: Телефон служебный и его могут использовать несколько человек

Comment: @eri Проблема с отсутствием значения `ForeignKey` решается установкой параметра [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) (например на [`SET_NULL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL)). Солидарен с [Александром](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/255680/Александр) в том, что здесь отлично подходит связь "один ко многим".

Comment: @eri, создайте еще одну модель телефона, если им  могут пользоваться несколько человек, а поле `phone` сделайте через `ForeignKey` опять же. Выставьте правильное поведение при удалении, как вам выше в комментариях описали и все будет хорошо.

Comment: @nomnoms12 её нельзя делать set null, это же потеря данных